# Calling SQL Server function PERCENTILE_CONT from LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to write a linq query, which uses PERCENTILE_CONT function without writing SQL code? That function doesn't exist [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: The question body should contains the question itself. See meta post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278902/should-i-repeat-the-title-in-the-question-body .

Comment: Question and answer in the post :)

Comment: It is possible. You can execute any SQL statement directly with Linq.

Comment: Indeed, the question should contain the *question*. First, are you *really* asking about Linq-To-SQL, the ORM that was only meant as an example and not updated in years? Or are you asking about LINQ on top of Entity Framework? That's a link to the LINQ to EF documentation - the wrong one

Comment: The correct link is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx but you want find the function there for good reasons: 1) ORMs are *not* meant for reporting and ranking functions are only meant for that. 2) different SQL Server versions support different ranking functions. Most of them wouldn't work even in SQL Server 2008 R2.  3) LINQ isn't SQL. It's meant to make loading *entities* easier, not execute ad-hoc queries.

Comment: You can create a view, stored procedure or function that produces what you want and map it to entites.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call any command or query using Linq To SQL. It looks like:

```
int result = context.ExecuteCommand("your command here", params object[])
```

and:

```
IEnumerable result = context.ExecuteQuery(typeof(yourType), "your query", params object[])

IEnumerable<TResult> result = context.ExecuteQuery<TResult>("your query", params object[])
```